# Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html

When embedding JavaScript in an HTML document, where is the proper place to put the `<script>` tags and included JavaScript? I seem to recall that you are not supposed to place these in the `<head>` section, but placing at the beginning of the `<body>` section is bad, too, since the JavaScript will have to be parsed before the page is rendered completely (or something like that). This seems to leave the *end* of the `<body>` section as a logical place for `<script>` tags.

So, where *is* the right place to put the `<script>` tags?

(This question references [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436154/why-does-the-call-to-this-jquery-function-fail-in-firefox), in which it was suggested that JavaScript function calls should be moved from `<a>` tags to `<script>` tags. I'm specifically using jQuery, but more general answers are also appropriate.)

Comment: in case you're also just looking for a simple solution and you're using some server side generator like Jekyll, i recommend including the script with it instead. so much simpler!

Comment: If coming from a search engine looking for this: Many of the answers are not clear ***exactly where the 'script tag' should be at the end***. If the 'script' tag is ***after*** '</body>', HTML validation will result in *"[Error: Stray start tag script](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fpmortensen.eu%2Ftemp2%2Fscript_tag_after_ending_body_tag_but_before_ending_html_tag.html)"* (check option *"source"* and click *"check"* to see the HTML source). It should be ***before*** '</body>'.  (The result is similar if the 'script' tag is at the very end, after the ***</html>*** tag.)

Comment: This is also addressed in *[Is it wrong to place the <script> tag after the </body> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/)*.

Comment: T.L.D.R. put it inside the `<head>` tag with `defer` attribute, or even better make your script `type='module'`. It is 2022 now.

Answer (score 2396, accepted):

Here's what happens when a browser loads a website with a `<script>` tag on it:

1. Fetch the HTML page (e.g. *index.html*)
2. Begin parsing the HTML
3. The parser encounters a `<script>` tag referencing an external script file.
4. The browser requests the script file. Meanwhile, the parser blocks and stops parsing the other HTML on your page.
5. After some time the script is downloaded and subsequently executed.
6. The parser continues parsing the rest of the HTML document.

Step #4 causes a bad user experience. Your website basically stops loading until you've downloaded all scripts. If there's one thing that users hate it's waiting for a website to load.

### Why does this even happen?

Any script can insert its own HTML via `document.write()` or other DOM manipulations. This implies that the parser has to wait until the script has been downloaded and executed before it can safely parse the rest of the document. After all, the script *could* have inserted its own HTML in the document.

However, most JavaScript developers no longer manipulate the DOM *while* the document is loading. Instead, they wait until the document has been loaded before modifying it. For example:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <script src="my-script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="user-greeting">Welcome back, user</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// my-script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // this function runs when the DOM is ready, i.e. when the document has been parsed
    document.getElementById("user-greeting").textContent = "Welcome back, Bart";
});
```

Because your browser does not know *my-script.js* isn't going to modify the document until it has been downloaded and executed, the parser stops parsing.

### Antiquated recommendation

The old approach to solving this problem was to put `<script>` tags at the bottom of your `<body>`, because this ensures the parser isn't blocked until the very end.

This approach has its own problem: the browser cannot start downloading the scripts until the entire document is parsed. For larger websites with large scripts and stylesheets, being able to download the script as soon as possible is very important for performance. If your website doesn't load within 2 seconds, people will go to another website.

In an optimal solution, the browser would start downloading your scripts as soon as possible, while at the same time parsing the rest of your document.

### The modern approach

Today, browsers support the `async` and `defer` attributes on scripts. These attributes tell the browser it's safe to continue parsing while the scripts are being downloaded.

#### async

```
<script src="path/to/script1.js" async></script>
<script src="path/to/script2.js" async></script>
```

Scripts with the async attribute are executed asynchronously. This means the script is executed as soon as it's downloaded, without blocking the browser in the meantime.
This implies that it's possible that script 2 is downloaded and executed before script 1.

According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async, 97.78% of all browsers support this.

#### defer

```
<script src="path/to/script1.js" defer></script>
<script src="path/to/script2.js" defer></script>
```

Scripts with the defer attribute are executed in order (i.e. first script 1, then script 2). This also does not block the browser.

Unlike async scripts, defer scripts are only executed after the entire document has been loaded.

*(To learn more and see some really helpful visual representations of the differences between async, defer and normal scripts check the first two links at the references section of this answer)*

## Conclusion

The current state-of-the-art is to put scripts in the `<head>` tag and use the `async` or `defer` attributes. This allows your scripts to be downloaded ASAP without blocking your browser.

The good thing is that your website should still load correctly on the 2% of browsers that do not support these attributes while speeding up the other 98%.

### References

- [async vs defer attributes](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html)
- [Efficiently load JavaScript with defer and async](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/)
- [Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started)
- [Async, Defer, Modules: A Visual Cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/jakub-g/385ee6b41085303a53ad92c7c8afd7a6#visual-representation)

Comment: I can't really imagine a lot of scenarios where DOM is not modified by  JavaScript. Could anyone give a example of a script that would use `async`?

Comment: Also when function are referenced by normally loaded JavaScript, from an `async` loaded JavaScript file, then it must wait for it to download right? It seems it gives me a uncaught reference error.

Comment: @Jori Common practice is to load your javascript asap (and non-blocking via async) and postpone any DOM manipulations until the "DOMContentLoaded" event is dispatched.

Comment: Defer does not seem to solve this issue on some browsers see http://stevesouders.com/hpws/rule-js-bottom.php

Comment: I'm not clear on what touches the DOM and what doesn't. Can you clarify? Is it safe to do an async load on something like jquery.js?

Comment: @Doug For example `document.write` operates on the dom. The question isn't *if* a script manipulates the dom, but *when* it does. As long as all dom manipulation happens after `domready` event has triggered, you're ok. jQuery is a library, and as such doesn't - or shouldn't - manipulate the dom by itself.

Comment: This answer is misleading. Modern browsers don't stop parsing when they reach a synchronous script tag that may affect the HTML, they just stop rendering/executing, and continue parsing optimistically to start downloading other resources that will probably be requested subsequently if no HTML is affected.

Comment: I guess that especially when getting scripts from a different domain like a CDN or subdomain they should be fine in the <head>
For me it feels better (I'm just using a subdomain), and the sticky header for example and other stuff works already while loading which doesn't feel slower. By the way, Facebook is loading tons of scripts from the <head> too ;-)
Cheers

Comment: I've tried to find a reference showing that if scripts in the head are async that the head is guaranteed to be ready (They have all loaded) before the body readyState becomes loaded. I can't find such a reference but based on waterfalls from Chrome, Firefox and IE11 in all cases tested the body becomes loaded after all async javascript has completed loading. So existing 'execute on dom ready' functionality appears safe. I just haven't found references that it always is.

Comment: How do you handle the case where a web application framework has a 'main' file with a <head> that loads scripts useful to all 'child' templates (e.g., JQuery), but where individual files need template-specific javascript?

Comment: Why the `async` and `defer` attributes are not used nowhere? I mean, I viewed a lot of HTML sources from internet, and I don't see the `async` and `defer` attributes anywhere. ... ?

Comment: How does dynamically building the script tag and appending it compare?  e.g.

{ var se = document.createElement('script'); se.type = 'text/javascript'; se.src = "//code.com/myscript.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(se, s); }

Is this similar to using defer?  Also, what if I add "se.async = true;" in there?  I've noticed third-party providers take this approach.

Comment: @Bart What if I put script in head - and it say registers handler for button click. Since the button is created in body, will I be able to register such a handler?

Comment: Great answer.  Any such recommendations on the `link` element / for stylesheets?  I found this http://codepen.io/tigt/post/async-css-without-javascript; but am surprised that the problem of loading external files would be addresses separately by file type/use, rather than once for all external content.

Comment: Nice answer. Can I assume that putting a `script` with `defer` is better to put before external css `style` tag inside head to take most benefit otherwise if put before `</body>` browser won't be able to request my defer script until css file is fetched.. Am I right?

Comment: As I have answered below, ES6 "modules", in many cases offer a better alternative to script on modern browsers.

Comment: The HTML guide [Introduction to HTML > What’s in the head? Metadata in HTML > Applying CSS and JavaScript to HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML#Applying_CSS_and_JavaScript_to_HTML) from Mozilla, might also a good place to see what best practices are currently established and actually followed, as it should be teaching the latest changes to the standards that this organization helps to steward.

(I have just submitted an edit along the lines of this answer. Feel free to improve on it.)

Comment: It was a very good refreshment, Everything you mentioned is true, I believe in general using defer is way better than going for async.

Answer (score 256):

Just before the closing body tag, as stated on *[Put Scripts at the Bottom](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)*:

> Put Scripts at the Bottom
>
> The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads. The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't start any other downloads, even on different hostnames.

Comment: Agreed with the concept and its explanation. But what happens if the user starts playing with the page. Suppose I've an AJAX dropdown which will start loading after the page has appeared to the user but while it is loading, the user clicks it! And what if a 'really impatient' user submits the form?

Comment: @Hermant Old comment but you may do the trick disabling the fields by default then enabling them using JS when the DOM is fully loaded. That's what Facebook seems to be doing nowadays.

Comment: Just tested this with chrome, to check if this is still the same. It Is. You can check the differences in page load time of your browsers here. http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/

Comment: If this is best practice, why does stack overflow include all their script tags in <head>? :-P

Comment: Can I add after the body closing tag or will it be cause any performance problem?

Comment: In some cases, especially in ajax heavy sites, loading in head can actually result in faster load times.  See: http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/ (note that the "live()" function is deprecated in jquery, but the article still applies with the "on()" or "delegate" function).  Loading in <head> may also be needed to guarantee correct behavior as pointed out by @Hermant.  Finally, http://modernizr.com/docs/ recommends placing its scripts in the <head> for reasons explained on its site.

Comment: In your quote it doesn't say anything about the `body` tag. Couldn't they be placed outside the body tag?

Comment: This advice is obsolete, from a time when content only came from the HTML.  Page start is too complicated to make such a general statement.  It still works now if your page doesn't need any code to execute for the initial render, and if it won't block basic interactivity .  However, if you are using something like vue without any server side rendering, putting your essential script at the end is prioritizing it below all images and css, making it both load and run much later than it should.

Comment: WARNING: No, this WAS a better practice.  put it inside the `<head>` tag with `defer` attribute, or even better make your script `type='module'`. It is 2022 now.

Answer (score 104):

Non-blocking script tags can be placed just about anywhere:

```
<script src="script.js" async></script>
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
<script src="script.js" async defer></script>
```

- [**`async`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) script will be executed asynchronously as soon as it is available
- [**`defer`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer) script is executed when the document has finished parsing
- **`async defer`** script falls back to the defer behavior if async is not supported

Such scripts will be executed asynchronously/after document ready, which means you cannot do this:

```
<script src="jquery.js" async></script>
<script>jQuery(something);</script>
<!--
  * might throw "jQuery is not defined" error
  * defer will not work either
-->
```

Or this:

```
<script src="document.write(something).js" async></script>
<!--
  * might issue "cannot write into document from an asynchronous script" warning
  * defer will not work either
-->
```

Or this:

```
<script src="jquery.js" async></script>
<script src="jQuery(something).js" async></script>
<!--
  * might throw "jQuery is not defined" error (no guarantee which script runs first)
  * defer will work in sane browsers
-->
```

Or this:

```
<script src="document.getElementById(header).js" async></script>
<div id="header"></div>
<!--
  * might not locate #header (script could fire before parser looks at the next line)
  * defer will work in sane browsers
-->
```

Having said that, asynchronous scripts offer these advantages:

- **Parallel download of resources**:
  Browser can download stylesheets, images and other scripts in parallel without waiting for a script to download and execute.
- **Source order independence**:
  You can place the scripts inside head or body without worrying about blocking (useful if you are using a CMS). Execution order still matters though.

It is possible to circumvent the execution order issues by using external scripts that support callbacks. Many third party JavaScript APIs now support non-blocking execution. Here is an example of [loading the Google Maps API asynchronously](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2014/05/google-maps-asynchronous-loading.html).

Comment: This is the correct answer for today - using this approach means it's easier to keep your widgets self contained, no need to do fancy `<head>` include logic.

Comment: I'm confused why you can't use `async` or `defer` when including jQuery as you specify in your second block: `<script src="jquery.js" async></script>`. Are you able to explain why? I thought I need to have the async tag in for performance—per the accepted answer—so my page can load even while jQuery is still loading]. Thanks!

Comment: @elbow 99% of times `<script src=jquery.js>` is followed by `$(function(){ ... })` blocks somewhere in the page. Asynchronous loading does not guarantee that jQuery will be loaded at the time browser tries to parse those blocks hence it will raise _$ is not defined_ error (you may not get the error if jQuery was loaded from cache). I answered a question about loading jQuery asynchronously and preserve `$(function(){ ... })`. I'll see if I could find it, or you can look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14811471/87015

Comment: @SalmanA Thank you! Yes, I fall in that 99%. I first need `jquery` lib to load, *then* my remaining `.js` scripts. When I declare `async` or `defer` on the `jquery` lib script tag, my `.js` scripts don't work. I thought `$(function(){ ... })`protected that—guess not. **Current solution:** I don't add `defer` or `async` on `jquery` lib script, but I do add `async` on my follow up `.js` scripts. Note: the reason I'm doing *any* of this is to make Google Page Speed happy. Thx again for the help! Any other advice is welcome. (Or a link to your previous answer). :)

Comment: @elbow See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21013975/87015, it will only give you an idea but not the complete solution. You could instead search for "jquery async loader libraries".

Comment: I am 100% in agreement with you!

Answer (score 44):

The standard advice, promoted by the *Yahoo!* Exceptional Performance team, is to put the `<script>` tags at the end of the document's `<body>` element so they don't block rendering of the page.

But there are some newer approaches that offer better performance, as described in [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435228/does-google-analytics-have-performance-overhead/435295#435295) about the load time of the Google Analytics JavaScript file:

> There are some [great slides](http://stevesouders.com/docs/googleio-20080529.ppt) by Steve Souders (client-side performance expert) about:
>
> - Different techniques to load external JavaScript files in parallel
> - their effect on loading time and page rendering
> - what kind of "in progress" indicators the browser displays (e.g. 'loading' in the status bar, hourglass mouse cursor).

Answer (score 40):

**The modern approach is using ES6 'module' type scripts**.

```
<script type="module" src="..."></script>
```

By default, modules are loaded asynchronously and deferred. i.e. you can place them anywhere and they will load in parallel and execute when the page finishes loading.

Further reading:

- [The differences between a script and a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652618/classic-scripts-vs-module-scripts-in-javascript/53821485#53821485)
- [The execution of a module being deferred compared to a script(Modules are deferred by default)](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules#defer)
- [Browser Support for ES6 Modules](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module)

Comment: Just a note that this will not work if you're just trying stuff out on your local filesystem with no server. At lest on Chrome you get a cross-origin error trying to load the js from the HTML even though they both have the same origin, your filesystem.

Answer (score 25):

If you are using jQuery then put the JavaScript code wherever you find it best and use `$(document).ready()` to ensure that things are loaded properly before executing any functions.

On a side note: I like all my script tags in the `<head>` section as that seems to be the cleanest place.

Comment: Note that using `$(document).ready()` doesn’t mean you can put your JavaScript *anywhere* you like – you still have to put it after the `<script src=".../jquery.min.js">` where you include jQuery, so that `$` exists.

Comment: It is not optimal to put script tags in the <head> section - this will delay display of the visible part of the page until the scripts are loaded.

Answer (score 21):

```
    <script src="myjs.js"></script>
</body>
```

The script tag should always be used before the **body close** or at the **bottom in HTML** file.

The Page will load with HTML and CSS and later JavaScript will load.

Check this if required:

http://stevesouders.com/hpws/rule-js-bottom.php

Comment: This actually answered the question. I was wondering nearly all the examples posted never gave the proper visual context of "end of the page"

Comment: This answer is very misleading and most probably wrong. The articles in 
[Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) and in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) suggests that synchronous JS (which is the case here) always blocks DOM construction and parsing which will result in delayed first-render. Therefore, you cannot see the content of the page until the JS file is fetched and finishes executing regardless of where you place your JS file in the HTML document as long as it is synchronous

Comment: It also references points made in 2009 and no longer relevant.

Comment: did you actually mean "otherwise you'll be able to see the content before loading the js file and that's bad?"

Comment: It is good practice not to put script tags at the end of the body or html code. Just like other declarative or meta information this should go in the head section reducing clutter of none content related information all over the place. Get used to using async or even better defer. Word Press can be a bit tricky, though. It puts the JavaScript in the wp_head but without the defer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944027/how-do-i-defer-or-async-this-wordpress-javascript-snippet-to-load-lastly-for-fas/20672324#20672324

Comment: The link is broken: *"File not found. 404 - the file wasn't found."*

Answer (score 13):

The **best** place to put `<script>` tag is before closing `</body>` tag, so the downloading and executing it doesn't block the browser to parse the HTML in document,

Also loading the JavaScript files externally has its own advantages like it will be cached by browsers and can speed up page load times, it separates the HTML and JavaScript code and help to manage the code base better.

But modern browsers also support some other optimal ways, like `async` and `defer` to load external JavaScript files.

### Async and Defer

Normally HTML page execution starts line by line. When an external JavaScript `<script>` element is encountered, HTML parsing is stopped until a JavaScript is download and ready for execution. This normal page execution can be changed using the `defer` and `async` attribute.

### `Defer`

When a defer attribute is used, JavaScript is downloaded parallelly with HTML parsing, but it will be execute only after full HTML parsing is done.

```
<script src="/local-js-path/myScript.js" defer></script>
```

### `Async`

When the async attribute is used, JavaScript is downloaded as soon as the script is encountered and after the download, it will be executed asynchronously (parallelly) along with HTML parsing.

```
<script src="/local-js-path/myScript.js" async></script>
```

### When to use which attributes

- If your script is independent of other scripts and is modular, use `async`.
- If you are loading script1 and script2 with `async`, both will run
  parallelly along with HTML parsing, as soon as they are downloaded
  and available.
- If your script depends on another script then use `defer` for both:
- When script1 and script2 are loaded in that order with `defer`, then script1 is guaranteed to execute first,
- Then script2 will execute after script1 is fully executed.
- Must do this if script2 depends on script1.
- If your script is small enough and is depended by another script
  of type `async` then use your script with no attributes and place it above all the `async` scripts.

Reference: *[External JavaScript JS File – Advantages, Disadvantages, Syntax, Attributes](http://knowledgehills.com/javascript/external-javascript-syntax-disadvantages.htm)*

Answer (score 10):

It turns out it can be everywhere.

You can defer the execution with something like jQuery so it doesn't matter where it's placed (except for a small performance hit during parsing).

Comment: XHTML will validate with script tags in the body, both strict and transitional. Style tags however may only be in the head.

Comment: Re *"it doesn't matter where it's placed"*: But not so the result is not [well-formed HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element)?

Comment: This answer is particularly un-useful because it does not answer the question of where I _should_ put `<script>` tags whatsoever (on top of being wrong).

Comment: Fair enough. It's been 13 years since I was that naive.

Answer (score 6):

The most conservative (and widely accepted) answer is "at the bottom just before the ending  tag", because then the entire DOM will have been loaded before anything can start executing.

There are dissenters, for various reasons, starting with the available practice to intentionally begin execution with a page onload event.

Comment: Re *"at the bottom""*: But *before* the ending body tag (`</body>`)? Can you make it clearer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 5):

It depends. If you are loading a script that's necessary to style your page / using actions in your page (like click of a button) then you better place it at the top. If your styling is 100% CSS and you have all fallback options for the button actions then you can place it at the bottom.

Or the best thing (if that's not a concern) is you can make a modal loading box, place your JavaScript code at the bottom of your page and make it disappear when the last line of your script gets loaded. This way you can avoid users using actions in your page before the scripts are loaded. And also avoid the improper styling.

Comment: Re *"place your JavaScript code at the bottom of your page"*: But ***before*** the ending body tag (`</body>`)? Can you make it clearer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Thanks for the modal idea! Webpages can load really slow on mobile and clicking buttons etc. can make them bug out permanently (until reloaded all over again) so some sort of loading screen or other way to block user interaction until the whole page is loaded might be a good idea in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Including scripts at the end is mainly used where the content/ styles of the web page is to be shown first.

Including the scripts in the head loads the scripts early and can be used before the loading of the whole web page.

If the scripts are entered at last the validation will happen only after the loading of the entire styles and design which is not appreciated for fast responsive websites.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the script and its usage the best possible (in terms of page load and rendering time) may be to not use a conventional <script>-tag per se, but to dynamically trigger the loading of the script asynchronously.

There are some different techniques, but the most straightforward is to use document.createElement("script") when the window.onload event is triggered. Then the script is loaded first when the page itself has rendered, thus not impacting the time the user has to wait for the page to appear.

This naturally requires that the script itself is not needed for the rendering of the page.

For more information, see the post *[Coupling async scripts](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/12/27/coupling-async-scripts/)* by Steve Souders (creator of [YSlow](http://yslow.org/), but now at Google).

Answer (score 2):

*Script* blocks DOM load until it's loaded and executed.

If you place scripts at the end of `<body>`, all of the DOM has a chance to load and render (the page will "display" faster). `<script>` will have access to all of those DOM elements.

On the other hand, placing it after the `<body>` start or above will execute the script (where there still aren't any DOM elements).

You are including jQuery which means you can place it wherever you wish and use [.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Answer (score 2):

You can place most of `<script>` references at the end of `<body>`.

But *if* there are active components on your page which are using external scripts, then their dependency (.js files) should come before that (ideally in the *head* tag).

Answer (score 2):

The best place to write your JavaScript code is at the end of the document after or right before the `</body>` tag to load the document first and then execute the JavaScript code.

```
<script> ... your code here ... </script>
</body>
```

And if you write in [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), the following can be in the head document and it will execute after the document loads:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Your code here...
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it throws `SyntaxError`

Comment: Your answer wasn't wrong but was in dire need of being updated.

Comment: It is not a good idea to put the scripts at the end of your body or html code. It is common practice to put this kind of meta information right where it belongs: in the head.

Comment: Re *"at the end of the document after ... the </body> tag"*: No, no, no!. If the 'script' tag is after '</body>', [HTML validation](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/script_tag_after_ending_body_tag_but_before_ending_html_tag.html) will result in "[Error: Stray start tag script](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fpmortensen.eu%2Ftemp2%2Fscript_tag_after_ending_body_tag_but_before_ending_html_tag.html)" (check option "source" and click "check" to see the HTML source). If it is before, [it validates](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/script_tag_before_ending_body_tag.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can add JavaScript code in an HTML document by employing the dedicated HTML tag `<script>` that wraps around JavaScript code.

The `<script>` tag can be placed in the `<head>` section of your HTML, in the `<body>` section, or after the `</body>` close tag, depending on when you want the JavaScript to load.

Generally, JavaScript code can go inside of the document `<head>` section in order to keep them contained and out of the main content of your HTML document.

However, if your script needs to run at a certain point within a page’s layout — like when using `document.write` to generate content — you should put it at the point where it should be called, usually within the `<body>` section.

Comment: Re *"after the </body> close tag"*: ***No, no, no!***. If the 'script' tag is ***after*** '</body>', [HTML validation](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/script_tag_after_ending_body_tag_but_before_ending_html_tag.html) will result in *"[Error: Stray start tag script](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fpmortensen.eu%2Ftemp2%2Fscript_tag_after_ending_body_tag_but_before_ending_html_tag.html)"* (check option *"source"* and click *"check"* to see the HTML source). If it is ***before***, [it validates](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/script_tag_before_ending_body_tag.html).

Answer (score 1):

- If you still care a lot about support and performance in Internet Explorer before [version 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10), it's best to *always* make your script tags the last tags of your HTML body. That way, you're certain that the rest of the DOM has been loaded and you won't block and rendering.
- If you don't care too much any more about in Internet Explorer before version 10, you might want to put your scripts in the head of your document and use `defer` to ensure they only run after your DOM has been loaded (`<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script1.js" defer></script>`). If you still want your code to work in Internet Explorer before version 10, don't forget to wrap your code in a `window.onload` even, though!

Comment: In the accepted answer, this is refered to as the “antiquated recommendation”. If you still mean it, you probably should produce some reference to back it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the webpage execution.

If the page that you want to display can not displayed properly  without loading JavaScript first then you should include the JavaScript file first.

But if you can display/render a webpage without initially download JavaScript file, then you should put JavaScript code at the bottom of the page. Because it will emulate a speedy page load, and from a user's point of view, it would seems like that the page is loading faster.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to put it before the `</body>` closing tag.

**Why?**
As per the official doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#a_hello_world!_example

> Note: The reason the instructions (above) place the  element
> near the bottom of the HTML file is that the browser reads code in the
> order it appears in the file.
>
> If the JavaScript loads first and it is supposed to affect the HTML
> that hasn't loaded yet, there could be problems. Placing JavaScript
> near the bottom of an HTML page is one way to accommodate this
> dependency. To learn more about alternative approaches, see Script
> loading strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Always, we have to put scripts before the closing body tag expect some specific scenario.

**For Example :**

```
`<html> <body> <script> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"; </script> </body> </html>`
```